# Progress Counter in Cocos2D

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I need a counter that updates a CCLabel every second.  I want it so the user can see how long they survived.  I'm not totally sure how to explain this so let me know if I can make things clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use timer ?

```
[NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(updateLabel:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]

-(void)updateLabel:(NSTimer*)t
{
  //Your code here
}
```

or in your render method you could check how many time has passed and update label accordingly, you can use for example code like this:

when launching game ( remember to release it when done with it):

```
gameStartDate = [[NSDate date] retain];
```

in draw method

```
[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate: gameStartDate];
//! update label code
```

For game I would probably use second option but both should suffice

Cheers,
Krzysztof Zabłocki